# Appending one string to another, but appendage is on new line not same line

Tags: php, string, file

I am appending something to each line in a file and then writing that to a new file.

But when I looked at the new file what it is doing is writing the line from the old file then writing what it should be appending to that line on a new line.

So if the first line in the old file is

```
A
```

The first and second line in the new file is

```
A
/appendage
```

What it should be is one line:

```
A /appendage
```

How can I fix my code so that the appendages are on the same line as what they are being appended to?

```
function writeTag($tags, $line, $file){
    foreach($tags as $t){
        $line .= " /".$t['tag']." ";
        fwrite($file, $line);
    }
}
$tagger = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt');
$lines = file('dictionary.txt');
$out = fopen("tagged.txt", "w");
foreach($lines as $line){
    $tags = $tagger->tag($line);
    writeTag($tags, $line, $out);
}
```

**Update:**

With bwoebi's updated answer adding IGNORE_NEW_LINES, the output file I am getting looks like:

```
A /DT A$ /DT A&E /DT A&E /DT  /NN A&M /DT A&M /DT  /NN
A&P /DT A&P /DT  /NN
```

What I am looking for is:

```
A /DT
A$ /DT
A&E /DT
A&E /DT /NN
A&M /DT
A&M /DT /NN
A&P /DT
A&P /DT /NN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file()` returns the strings until the newline (`\n`) ***inclusive***: so cut it off when there's one `\n` as the last character of the string.

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ($line[strlen($line)-1] == "\n")
        $line = substr($line, 0, -1);
    $tags = $tagger->tag($line);
    writeTag($tags, $line, $out);
}
```

---

**Update**: Better method: use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`. This constant prevents that the newlines are added.

```
$lines = file('dictionary.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

---

**Answer to updated question:** append a newline each time you have finished with one `$tag`:

```
function writeTag($tags, $line, $file){
    foreach($tags as $t){
        $line .= " /".$t['tag']." ";
        fwrite($file, $line."\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my php file to your update adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and now it is not writing the file again.

Comment: @JayGatz I cannot guess how a line without newline affects the $tagger->tag function. Does it work when you write `$tagger->tag($line."\n");`?

Comment: Actually it was working. I had to give my server some time to display the new file. Except, now it is ignoring all the new lines. I'll update my question with what the output file looks like and what it should look like or what I want it to look like. I'll update the question and let you know.

Comment: I updated my question with the output I am getting with your updated answer using `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and the output that I am looking for.

Comment: That still doesn't do it. My file looks like: `A /DT A$ /DT A&E /DT A&E /DT  /NN A&M /DT A&M /DT  /NN`

Comment: @JayGatz Oh, okay; now better?

Comment: What did you change? It looks the same to me.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, by the way. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @JayGatz I added a `."\n"` to the fwrite ...  When this answer solves your problem, please consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.